# error while cron scheduling a sh script

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, cron, django

This is my shell script which i want to schedule using cron job.

parser.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source .profile
workon venv
cd /home/ashish/deployments/myproject

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings_production
python /home/ashish/deployments/myproject/myproject/manage.py parse_data
```

Cron job-

```
*/15 * * * * . /home/ashish/parser.sh
```

Whenever this cron job runs i receive a mail with errors:

```
/bin/sh: 6: /home/ashish/parser.sh: source: not found
/bin/sh: 7: /home/ashish/parser.sh: workon: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashish/deployments/myproject/myproject/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

When i run this script from terminal -

```
. parser.sh    #this gives no error

sh parser.sh   #this gives errors
/bin/sh: 6: /home/ashish/parser.sh: source: not found
/bin/sh: 7: /home/ashish/parser.sh: workon: not found
```

What can be the possible error in this script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*/15 * * * * . /home/ashish/parser.sh
```

`cron` uses `sh`, not `bash`, so when you source the script (that's what the `.` does), it is run under `sh`, not `bash`. Remove the `.`.

Also, the `PATH` for cron is limited. Specify the full paths to commands you use, such as `workon`, or set `PATH` yourself.

Comment: ...and use a full path for the `source .profile` in our script, too

Comment: changed `source .profile` to `source /home/ashish/.profile` and  `*/15 * * * * . /home/ashish/parser.sh` to `*/15 * * * * /home/ashish/parser.sh` . Now its working fine! Thanks a lot @muru

Answer (score 0):

To run the script like it's running on your own account (with bash) change your crontab to the following:

```
*/15 * * * * sudo -u ashish /home/ashish/parser.sh
```

This will run the script almost as if you executed it from the command line on your own account.